# Exception when Intent Data to another Activity android.content.Context.getPackageName()

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-recyclerview, android-context

Hello guys  iam trying to get Data to putExtra  => Intent from an Adapter to another Activity but every time i try to get data from the Adapter to the Activity  it Gives me this Exception that

> java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()'

so i tried to Enter the Context class i found it too many Errors  cant fix that till now

what makes me really Believe that the problem with the Context is that when i Tried to use [TinyDB](https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo)

it need to define the Object  inside the Adapter

> tinyDB = new TinyDB(mContext);

the program Crashed and Gives Me this Exception

```
    W/System.err: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
W/System.err:     at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:128)
                  at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:4910)
                  at com.team.plustegara.Views.Models.Adapters.EventsAdapter$1.onClick(EventsAdapter.java:83)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5647)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22465)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:754)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:163)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6238)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
```

i tried to Fix that but still cant handle the Context problem

> Here is my Adapter

```
public class EventsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EventsAdapter.EventsHolder> {

public EventsAdapter(List<EventsModel> list, Context mContext) {
    this.list = list;
    this.mContext = mContext;
}

private List<EventsModel> list;
private Context mContext;




FirebaseAuth mAuth;
DatabaseReference dbRef;

@NonNull
@Override
public EventsHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.events_row_item, parent, false);
    EventsHolder holder = new EventsHolder(view);
    return holder;

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final EventsHolder holder, int position) {


    final EventsModel listy = list.get(position);


    holder.eventTitle.setText(listy.getTitle());
    holder.eventDate.setText(listy.getEventDate());
    holder.eventCosts.setText("Event Costs " + listy.getCosts());

    Picasso.get()
            .load(listy.getEventImage())
            .fit()
            .centerCrop()
            .placeholder(R.drawable.gradients_card)
            .into(holder.eventImage);

    holder.cardViewEvents.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            try {

                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, ShowActivityEvents.class);

                intent.putExtra("EventImage", listy.getEventImage());
                intent.putExtra("EventTitle", listy.getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("EventDate", listy.getEventDate());
                intent.putExtra("EventCosts", listy.getCosts());
                intent.putExtra("EventDescription", listy.getDescription());
                intent.putExtra("eventID", listy.getPostID());
                   mContext.startActivity(intent);

                dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("PlusTeam");
                mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


                String userName = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName();

                String postID = listy.getPostID();
                dbRef.child("Events").child(postID).child("Views").push().setValue(userName);


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });



    String postID = listy.getPostID();
    DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("PlusTeam");
    databaseReference.child("Events").child(postID).child("Views").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            long ViewsCount = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
            holder.txtViews.setText(String.valueOf(ViewsCount));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toasty.error(mContext, databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

public class EventsHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    @BindView(R.id.EventImageCard)
    ImageView eventImage;
    @BindView(R.id.txtEventTitle)
    TextView eventTitle;
    @BindView(R.id.txtEventDate)
    TextView eventDate;
    @BindView(R.id.txtEventCosts)
    TextView eventCosts;
    @BindView(R.id.cardView_EventsCard)
    CardView cardViewEvents;
    @BindView(R.id.txtEventsViews) TextView txtViews;

    public EventsHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);



       }
    }


}
```

> here is my Activity which receive the Extras from the Adapter

```
public class ShowActivityEvents extends AppCompatActivity {



DatabaseReference dbRef;
FirebaseAuth mAuth;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    checkIfUserAlreadyAccepttheEvent();

}

private void checkIfUserAlreadyAccepttheEvent() {



    final String postID = getIntent().getExtras().getString("eventID");
    final String UserID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();


    dbRef.child(postID).child("PeopleComing")
            .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                public static final String TAG = "ShowEvents";

                @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onChildAdded: " + dataSnapshot);

                    String peopleCount = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());
                    txtPeopleComing.setText( peopleCount + " People Comming");

                    if (dataSnapshot.child(UserID).exists()) {

                        btnIamIn.setEnabled(false);



                    } else {
                        btnIamIn.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                }
                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    Toasty.error(ShowActivityEvents.this, "Error code : " + 1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }
            });
}



@BindView(R.id.btnIamIn)
Button btnIamIn;
@BindView(R.id.txtPeopleComingCount)
TextView txtPeopleComing;

@BindView(R.id.imgEventPost)
ImageView imgEvent;
@BindView(R.id.txtEventTitle) TextView txtEventTitle;
@BindView(R.id.txtEventDescription) TextView txtEventDescription;
@BindView(R.id.txtEventCost) TextView txtEventCost;
@BindView(R.id.txtEventDate) TextView txtEventDate;
Intent intent;




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_show_events2);



    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("PlusTeam");
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    try {
        loadDataFromAdapter();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

private void loadDataFromAdapter() {

    String Image = getIntent().getExtras().getString("EventImage");
    String Title = getIntent().getExtras().getString("EventTitle");
    String Date = getIntent().getExtras().getString("EventDate");
    String Costs = getIntent().getExtras().getString("EventCosts");
    String Description = getIntent().getExtras().getString("EventDescription");


    GlideApp.with(this)
            .load(Image)
            .fitCenter()
            .into(imgEvent);

    txtEventTitle.setText(Title);
    txtEventDescription.setText(Description);
    txtEventDate.setText(Date);
    txtEventCost.setText(Costs);

}

@OnClick(R.id.btnIamIn) public void addPersonToEvent(){


    String UserName = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getDisplayName();
    String userID = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();


    String postID = getIntent().getExtras().getString("eventID");
    dbRef.child(postID)
            .child("PeopleComing").setValue(UserName);
    btnIamIn.setEnabled(false);



  }



}
```

Finally just wanted to say i searched for this kind of Problem in Google and inside questions in Stack but didn't worked 
so any Suggestions

Comment: You have problems with context. How do you pass it to Adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass your context in adapter like in the example below

Activity

```
adapter = new EventsAdapter(myList,MainActivity.this);
```

Fragment

```
adapter = new EventsAdapter(myList,getActivity());
```

Or another way

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    v.getContext().startActivity(v.getContext(), ShowActivityEvents.class);
}
```

Comment: can you please tell me how to handle that out side the OnClick(View v) 
like in side adapter

Comment: Like you did in your code, but when you create adapter you should pass your context like in first or second example. It depends what do u have activity or fragment

Comment: the case is pass context to tinyDB = new TinyDB(context);   the problem is here  , you've fixed the OnClick method  but  out side didn't work

Comment: Just create another question, because you need to show up how you are passing context, code with TinyDb and the error

Comment: thanks dude i fixed it ,  just needed to add   in  onCreateViewHolder method  

contex = parent.getContext();